# SED command to get complete string after a particular pattern

Tags: unix, sed

SED command not picking the first occurrence

Thanks
sri

Inputstring:

```
xxxxyyy>|D1:RAPO|D2:Bsdeje|D3:37474|D4:|D5:|vddtgbjkkuyddvh
```

Output:

```
D1:RAPO|D2:Bsdeje|D3:37474|D4:|D5:|vddtgbjkkuyddvh
```

sed used :

```
sed - e ‘s/\(^.*D1:\)\(.*\)\(\|A4:.*$)/\2/‘
```

Issue: When multiple occurrences not picking the first occurrence

Example

Input

```
xxxxyyy>|D1:RAPO|D2:Bsdeje|D3:37474|D4:|D5:|vddtgbjkkuyddvh,22234”202394754:CA1:166:644:234”asdrdr-2445
```

With Above sed

Output:

```
166:644:234”asdrdr-2445
```

Expected output:

```
RAPO|D2:Bsdeje|D3:37474|D4:|D5:|vddtgbjkkuyddvh,22234”202394754:CA1:166:644:234”asdrdr-2445
```

What changes need to be done for Bove SED?

Comment: Your shown `sed` command is invalid: 1) extra whitespace between `-` and `e`.
2) unmatched parentheses. 3) usage of smart quotes, not single quotes.
Please edit your question with copy&paste of your used command instead
of typing the command by hand.

Comment: I agree with the comments above. ALSO, your `sed` is looking for `|A4:` but your sample data doesn't have it (that I can find). AND what do you mean by *multiple occurrences*. I don't see any repeating data. Use a 2nd line to highlight where the duplication is. Something like `#------^-dupe-^-------------^--dupe--^-------` added below the line of your sample data should help. Good luck.

Comment: I've added a "\" char before the last `)`. Then `echo "xxxxyyy>|D1:RAPO|D2:Bsdeje|D3:37474|D4:|D5:|vddtgbjkkuyddvh,22234”202394754:CA1:166:644:234”asdrdr-2445" | sed '
s/\(^.*D1:\)\(.*\)\(\|A4:.*$\)/\2/'` produces output of `RAPO|D2:Bsdeje|D3:37474|D4:|D5:|vddtgbjkkuyddvh,22234”202394754:CA1:166:644:234”asdrdr-2445` . I hope that helps. Good luck.